# Running post-deploy and post-scale scripts on Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, azure, autoscaling

Coming from AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I'm familiar with the `scripts.config` file that allows me to specify commands to run after deploy as well as just after new scaled instances are created.

Is there an equivalent facility in Azure?  Is it possible to run scripts post deploy and more importantly, is there a way to differentiate between the two scenarios like on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Are you referring to scaling VMs in an availability set, or cloud service roles, or App Services?

Comment: Scaling WebApps.

Comment: There is no such feature for Web Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Cloud Services (web/worker roles) have [startup tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx), but Web Apps have no such feature.